# INSERT with SELECT DISTINCT and another field included?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, sqlite

I have a products table and each product have a category field *(this is not up to me to change and I need to read the data from it as it is)*, from the product table I wanted to update a category table with unique categories only (I also use a `IFNULL` to deal with empty categories), this is what I have so far that works:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO categories (name) 
                    SELECT DISTINCT(IFNULL(category, \"Uncategorized\")) AS category_name
                    FROM products 
                        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                            SELECT name FROM categories 
                                WHERE name = category_name)";
```

With the above query I am able to update the categories with unique category fields and every time I need to run it, it will add only categories that does not exist to the table.

But besides the above I also need to include a profile id with each category inserted something like this, which does not work:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO categories (profile_id, name)
                    SELECT " + profileId.ToString() + ",
                        DISTINCT(IFNULL(category, \"Uncategorized\")) AS category_name
                    FROM products 
                        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                            SELECT name FROM categories 
                                WHERE name = category_name 
                                    AND profile_id = @profileId)";
```

**Is there a way I could acomplish this with a query ?**

The above gives me a message:

```
SQLite error near "DISTINCT": syntax error
```

SqliteMan error:

```
Query Error: near "DISTINCT": syntax error Unable to execute statement
```

Let me know if I havent been clear and what should I be more clear about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `DISTINCT` keyword incorrectly: it is not a function.  Try instead:

```
"INSERT INTO categories (profile_id, name)
 SELECT DISTINCT '"+profileId.ToString()+"', IFNULL(category, 'Uncategorized')
 FROM   products
 WHERE  category_name NOT IN (
          SELECT name FROM categories WHERE profile_id = "'+profileId.ToString()+"'
        )
"
```

One assumes that `profileId.ToString()` is guaranteed to be safe from SQL injection, or else you would be escaping it/passing it as a parameter to a prepared statement?

Comment: Yes it is safe and internally used only, that worked wornderfully thank you.